# smali: String Constants

Tags: android, smali

Is there anything else that must be done to load a String constant into a register, and then using it in a method invocation, besides doing:

```
const-string v6, "TEST CONSTANT"
invoke-static {v6, p1}, Landroid/util/Log;->wtf(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
```

?

the following block of instructions

```
iget-object v4, p0, Lcom/mypackage/MyClass;->myList:Ljava/util/List;
invoke-interface {v4, p1}, Ljava/util/List;->contains(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
move-result v5
if-eqz v5, :cond_not_met_0
const-string v6, "TEST CONSTANT"
invoke-static {v6, p1}, Landroid/util/Log;->wtf(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
:cond_not_met_0

invoke-interface {v4, p2}, Ljava/util/List;->contains(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
move-result v5
if-eqz v5, :cond_not_met_1
invoke-static {v6, p2}, Landroid/util/Log;->wtf(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
:cond_not_met_1
```

gave me the following logcat error messages:

```
10-29 23:37:37.191: W/dalvikvm(515): VFY: register1 v6 type 2, wanted ref
10-29 23:37:37.241: W/dalvikvm(515): VFY: bad arg 0 (into Ljava/lang/String;)
10-29 23:37:37.241: W/dalvikvm(515): VFY:  rejecting call to Landroid/util/Log;.wtf (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
10-29 23:37:37.241: W/dalvikvm(515): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x71 at 0x0028
```

Comment: That is very strange. I don't see anything immediately wrong with the code you mentioned.

Comment: is there a constraint or limit on the number of registers that can be used within a method? for this method where i have the above invocation, it was orginally declared as `.registers 7`, and i had to increase it to `.registers 10` for my use.

Comment: Nope. Is there any code between const-string and invoke-static?

Comment: Actually, yes. there is a limit. But you're no-where near it :)

Comment: In case it was missed, i managed to change some stuff and got things to work, but not sure what the exact reason is. It's described in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicions in this case are correct. The problem is because at the second Log->wtf instance, v6 was not necessarily set.

As to *why* this happens, it's important to note that very little verification is done when re-assembling the bytecode. In many cases, the assembler simply does not have enough information to do this level of verification - this would require the assembler have knowledge of the full set of classes that will be present when the application runs, similar to the case of deodexing (-o) or generating register info (-r).

These types of problems are caught by dalvik when verifies the bytecode, which is exactly what the error you mentioned is from.

Additionally, you mention "the values i used for p1 and p2 would have failed both if-eqz tests". This does not matter to dalvik's bytecode verifier. The verifier makes sure that *all* code paths are valid. It can't know or assume any particular value for the parameters that are passed in to the method.

If you want to see some additional information related to how the register types are propagated throughout the method, you can try the -r option for baksmali.

```
# grab the full framework directory from your device
adb pull /system/framework framework
# run baksmali with the -r command
baksmali -r ARGS,DEST,FULLMERGE -d framework <apk_or_dex_file>
```

This will add comments before/after every instruction with detailed information about the types of registers at that position.

Answer (score 0):

i changed some things around and got it to work, but i'm not sure why...

the change i did was to move the constant loading (`const-string v6, "TEST CONSTANT"`) outside of the "if-block", resulting in

```
const-string v6, "TEST CONSTANT"
iget-object v4, p0, Lcom/mypackage/MyClass;->myList:Ljava/util/List;

invoke-interface {v4, p1}, Ljava/util/List;->contains(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
move-result v5
if-eqz v5, :cond_not_met_0
invoke-static {v6, p1}, Landroid/util/Log;->wtf(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
:cond_not_met_0

invoke-interface {v4, p2}, Ljava/util/List;->contains(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
move-result v5
if-eqz v5, :cond_not_met_1
invoke-static {v6, p2}, Landroid/util/Log;->wtf(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
:cond_not_met_1
```

i suspect the reason for the initial problem is that if the flow bypassed the first "if-block" but entered the second "if-block", then the register `v6` would not yet have been loaded before it was used.

the reason why i'm not so sure is because, when i ran the reassembled programme, the values i used for `p1` and `p2` would have failed both `if-eqz` tests (i.e. the flow would enter both "if-blocks").

so it seemed that,
1. the check for register `v6` to be loaded before it was used was done preemptively before the actual control flow?
2. i thought such checking is only done at compile time?

i'm posting this as an answer as i needed more space to explain what i did. however, i'm still curious as to why such a change got it to work, so if anyone could give an explanation i'll mark that as the answer, thanks!

Comment: You should probably update your question with the additional info (the original bytecode snippet, for example), and then refactor your answer to only have the stuff relevant to the solution. In fact, you should have included that to begin with, which would have given me enough information to answer your question to begin with :)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, i should have included at least up till the end of the second "if-block". Thing is i kept thinking that the problem lied in how i wrote the two statements in my OP, and it totally failed to occur that the second invoke statement could cause problems! ;-p